# std::async variant which works over a collection

Tags: c++, concurrency, c++11, future

Using `std::async` I was wondering whether it is possible to have a helper function, which creates `std::future`s from a collection (one future for every collection element).

Often I have the following situation:

```
auto func = []( decltype(collection)::reference value ) {
  //Some async work
};

typedef std::result_of<decltype(func)>::type ResultType;
std::vector<std::future<ResultType>> futures;
futures.reserve(collection.size());

// Create all futures
for( auto& element : collection ) {
  futures.push_back(std::async(func, element));
}

// Wait till futures are done
for( auto& future : futures ) {
  future.wait();
}
```

To be able to easily reuse this I came up with the following partial code:

```
template< class Function, class CT, class... Args>
std::vector<std::future<typename std::result_of<Function(Args...)>::type>>
async_all( Function&& f, CT& col ) {

    typedef typename std::result_of<Function(Args...)>::type ResultType;
    std::vector<std::future<ResultType>> futures;
    futures.reserve(collection.size());

    for( auto& element : collection ) {
        futures.push_back(std::async(func, element));
    }
}
return futures;
```

Now I have to solve the `Args` problem, since in `async_all`, `Args` cannot be deduced anymore. The only thing I currently can think of is another functor, which converts an element in collection to `Args`.
Is there any more elegant solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

You're almost there.  The collection passed to `async_all` has all the information we need to uniquely determine the function argument type; the only question is how to extract this information. Using the `auto` keyword in the function signature, we can write the return type after the function arguments.  This not only produces a cleaner signature, but also lets us use the argument values themselves together with `decltype` in deducing return types.  For instance:

```cpp
template<typename F, typename CT>
auto reduce(F f, CT coll) -> decltype(f(*begin(coll), *begin(coll));
```

Of course, there are other ways to determine argument types for provided functions (using function signature deduction with templates). However, these approaches can fail for cases involving overloaded functions and/or templated function objects.

The following code compiles and runs properly (prints "x=1" 10 times) under gcc 4.8 (earlier versions should work just fine). Notice how we don't even have to explicitly mention `std::future`: we can use decltype directly on the `std::async` statement to deduce it's type.

```cpp
#include <future>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<class Function, class CT>
auto async_all(Function f, CT col)
    -> std::vector<decltype(std::async(f, *std::begin(col)))>
{
    std::vector<decltype(std::async(f, *std::begin(col)))> futures;
    futures.reserve(col.size());

    for (auto& element : col) {
        futures.push_back(std::async(f, element));
    }
    return futures;
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    for (auto& f : async_all([](int x) { cout << "x = " << x << endl; }, 
                             vector<int>(10, 1)))
       f.get();
}
```

(`async_all` is evaluated just once here, as the spec guarantees for range expressions in range-based  for loops)